# How to call Javascript from Java (JavaFX) code

Tags: javascript, java, javafx-8

How to call Javascript from Java (JavaFX) code

In my code, i have to export color/images to photoshop with the help of javascript.

we are developing application which works parallel with Photoshop application. So I need to send images / colors from my application to Photoshop. I have script (Photoshop scripts) which are written using JavaScript.

Now I need help for how to call those scripts in my code. I don't have any idea how to call (or how to use) javascript from Java code

Comment: To me at least, all the different parts in your question (Java, Photoshop, Javascript) are not related to each other at all. I have no clue what you're trying to do, why you're trying to do it, and how. Would you mind explaining what your overall problem is that you're trying to solve here?

Comment: we are developing application which works parallel with Photoshop application. So I need to send images / colors from my application to Photoshop. I have script (Photoshop scripts) which are written using JavaScript. Now I need help for how to call those scripts in my code

Comment: The JavaScript engine in Java 8 is called Nashorn, and the documentation is here: [Java Platform, Standard Edition Nashorn User's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/nashorn/intro.html)

Comment: Thank you sir, let me try, if it works